# How to make an object visible in only one view in blender 2.83?

Tags: visibility

How to make an object visible in only one view in blender 2.83? For example let's say i want to view a cube only from top view , whenever i switch to front or side view the cube will not appear. Blender 2.78 had the right/front/top side only option.

Comment: "*Blender 2.79 had the right/front/top side only option*" It did? Where?

Comment: i was watching cg geek's tutorial and he specified an image's view to right only ,
Star Wars Blender Tutorial _ Star Destroyer 1 of 2 at  3:15 , even though it was in blender 2.78 not 2.79.

Comment: Do you mean the background picture?

Comment: yes , he adjusted the pictures to apppear in one view only .

Comment: Background images have this functionality, not all objects.

Comment: then , how do i do it ?I can't find the option in image properties of the properties panel.

Comment: I think that option is no longer there because if you add an image  in front view you basically can't see it when you go to side view, what you do have is a checkbox for perspective view and orthograpic view  (Display Perspective, Dsplay Orthographic)so you can turn it on or off